# in openfoam, paraview cannot connect to X server

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, paraview, xserver, openfoam

My background in ubuntu and OpenFOAM: I started to learn to simulate in OpenFoam this week. I have windows 10 on my laptop and downloaded ubuntu 18.04 from the app store. In ubuntu OpenFOAM and paraview are installed by a guy from the ICT-helpdesk (paraview has already worked). Also, the Xming X server is installed.

My question: During the first tutorial (cavity) you must visualize the data with paraview. So after the guy installed everything, I could use paraview. Now I closed ubuntu and started again. If I now call paraFoam into action I get the following lines:
    Created temporary 'cavity.foam'
    paraview: cannot connect to X server

Does anybody know what to do with this? I checked this forum and I checked google, but could not find anybody with this specific problem.

Sincerely,
Me

Comment: Why not using ParaView instead of paraFOAM ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that xming is running then run the following on your ubuntu terminal:

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0
```

Now you can run paraview:

```
paraview
```